# Is it possible for dot product and cross product of two vectors to be zero at the same time?

Tags: vectors

Is it possible for dot product and cross product of two vectors to be zero at the same time ?

Comment: That's not a physics question.

Comment: Try a zero vector ;)

Comment: it is asked in my physics question book ,, how can u say that it is not a physics q?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137329/2451

Comment: Amrit, I suspect ACuriousMind means it's a question about maths with no immediate physical relevance. Write down the expressions for the dot and cross products of two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ with an angle $\theta$ between them, and then set them both to zero and you should be able to see the answer.

Comment: thanxxx ... i realize what should i do now ,